# Recording with sound not possible in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, audio, virtual-machine, screen-capture

Is it possible to not only video capture in VirtualBox but also record the audio coming from the VirtualBox? When I try to select the right device to record I get this, which bascially means the audio device is already in use.

> The virtual machine execution may run into an error condition as described below. We suggest that you take an appropriate action to avert the error.
>   Some audio devices (PCM_in, PCM_mic) could not be opened. Guest applications generating audio output or depending on audio input may hang. Make sure your host audio device is working properly. Check the logfile for error messages of the audio subsystem.

```
Error ID: HostAudioNotResponding
Severity: Warning
```

How can I record video with sound from VirtualBox?

**EDIT:**

I tried recording from inside VM. It still does not work. Probably because I am using the virtual soundcard inside an audio application.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit not a very desirable solution: install a screen recording utility on the guest system, such as Fraps. It means you would have to install it on each guest system, but saves you from fighting with the driver/device issues you are facing.

Edit:
Set your virtual audio device to **ICH AC97**. [Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/143799)
And install Guest Additions. [Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/143416)

Comment: I edited my answer. It unfortunately it does not pick up any sound from inside the VM as well if I pick the same audio devices.

Comment: Does virtualbox give you the error, or the guest OS?

Comment: What OS? Are you specifically using the audio device for something? Try restarting. Try uninstalling the device and then restart, letting windows reinstall it.

Comment: I use Linux. When I screenrecord from inside the VM I don't get any errors, simply no sound. When I try to record from outside I either get the warning in the screenrecorder or the VM. Depending on which occupies the Audio Device second.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using SimpleScreenRecorder. Install using the commands here: http://hackerspace.kinja.com/screen-recording-in-linux-1686055808

It records sound and video here from lubuntu guest in oracle VM.